# on windows, git show HEAD^, does not work and does not display the parent commit,

Tags: git

I'm currently learning git by following the book "pro git" by Scott Chacon.

In chapter 7 "git tool", the author mentioned that `^` sign is used to find out the ancestry of a commit.

e.g. to display the parent commit of the commit that is currently pointed to by the HEAD pointer

```
git show HEAD^
```

But after I pressed enter, instead of executing the command, the command prompt asked for `more`

[image]

After I have pressed enter a few more times, an error is displayed

[image]

Why is this happening? I'm currently using command prompt on windows.

Comment: What version of git do you have? Compare it to the version used in the book.

Comment: @byxor i'm using git version 2.10.2.windows.1. btw, SLaks has given a solution that worked for me. Thanks for helping out anyway! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`^` is the escape character for the Windows command prompt.

Use `^^` to escape it and run a command that includes a single `^`:

```
git show HEAD^^
```

Comment: thank you very much for helping out! work like a charm!

Comment: Ah windows. It never fails to surprise me.